# trouble with making a dropout stack with linked lists in java

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

So in my assignment, I have to implement a dropout stack in Java. A drop-out stack behaves like a stack in every respect except that if the stack size is n, then when the n+1 element is pushed, the first element is lost. In my case, I have set n=5. My code is running fine, but when I add more elements after the 5th element, the element at the bottom is not being removed. It just keeps stacking the new ones on top like a normal stack. Please help me understand how to fix this. Here is my code for the stack implementation:

```
/**
 * Represents a linked implementation of a stack.
 *
 * @author Java Foundations 
 * @version 4.0
 */
    public class DropOutStack<T> implements StackADT<T>
    {
    private int count; //number of elements in the stack
    private LinearNode<T> top; 

    /*Declares the maximum number of elements in the stack*/
    private final int n = 5;//max size
    private LinearNode<T> prev;
    private LinearNode<T> curr;

    /**
     * Creates an empty stack.
     */
    public DropOutStack()
    {
        count = 0;
        top = null;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified element to the top of this stack.
     * @param element element to be pushed on stack
     */
    public void push(T element)
    {
        LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T>(element);

        /*Verifies that the number of elements in the stack is
         * less than n. If yes, adds the new element to the stack*/
        if (count < n) {
            temp.setNext(top);
            top = temp;
            count++;
        }
        /*Verifies if the number of elements in the stack is greater
         * than or equal to n or not, and that the n is not equal to one.
         * If yes, removes the first element from the stack and adds
         * the new element to the stack*/
        else if(count>=n && n!=1) {
            prev = top;
            curr = top.getNext();

            while(curr != null) {
                prev = prev.getNext();
                curr = curr.getNext();
            }
            prev.setNext(null);
            count--;

            push(element);
        }
        else //if n=1
        {
            top.setElement(element);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the element at the top of this stack and returns a
     * reference to it. 
     * @return element from top of stack
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the stack is empty
     */
    public T pop() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");

        T result = top.getElement();
        top = top.getNext();
        count--;

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the element at the top of this stack.
     * The element is not removed from the stack.  
     * @return element on top of stack
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the stack is empty  
     */
    public T peek() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {

        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");
        T result = top.getElement();

        return result;

    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this stack is empty and false otherwise. 
     * @return true if stack is empty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (count ==0);

    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this stack.
     * @return number of elements in the stack
     */
    public int size()
    {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this stack. 
     * @return string representation of the stack
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "";
        LinearNode<T> current = top;
        while (current != null) {
            result = current.getElement() + "\n" + result;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return result;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are iterating too far over the linked list in your `else if (count >= n && n != 1)` block.

Currently you terminate when `curr == null`, but if `curr` is `null` then `prev` is the last node in the list, who's next value is already `null` (`curr`).

To resolve this, change the loop condition to `curr.getNext() != null`. Since you always want to push the element, just do that at the end and simplify the logic, given the precondition that n (the max size [poor name]) should be at least 1.

```
/**
 * @pre. n >= 1
 */
public void push(T element) {
    if (count >= n) {
        assert top != null;
        prev = null;
        curr = top;
        while (curr.getNext() != null) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
        if (prev != null) {
            prev.setNext(null);
        } else {
            top = null;
        }
        count--;
    }
    LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<>(element);
    temp.setNext(top);
    top = temp;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: @JohnnySack No problem. With any work involving data structures sometimes the best thing you can do is draw the structure and actions with pen and paper so you can visualize what is happening.

Comment: I have a question with another problem. Would you mind helping me with it?

Comment: @JohnnySack I'd suggest having a go at trying to tackle it yourself first (perhaps with a clear head). If you're still struggling speak to your peers or tutor (assuming that is also assignment work). As a last resort ask here. One of the best way to learn is to try and make mistakes and identify the cause the problem. Plus there's always way more satisfaction in solving a problem yourself!