# How do implement a drop out stack using a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have set up a linked list and now I need to change the push method so everytime a new element is added, the first is removed. And suggestions on ways to achieve this ?

```
    public void push(T element)
    {

        LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T>(element);

        temp.setNext(top);
        top = temp;
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trouble with making a dropout stack with linked lists in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857454/trouble-with-making-a-dropout-stack-with-linked-lists-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, there is an interface called a `Deque` (Double-ended queue). It allows you to remove/add from the head and the tail of the list. In your case, create a function that when you `addLast`, you also remove `removeFirst` or the other way around.

See this for more details:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

EDIT:

This may help too,
[trouble with making a dropout stack with linked lists in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857454/trouble-with-making-a-dropout-stack-with-linked-lists-in-java)